# Debugging .aspx in WAP

Tags: asp.net

In WAP, should you expect to get errors when debugging an .aspx during compile time?  I'm not getting any errors when my .aspx has errors until runtime when using Web Application Projects.  I never really thought about it, because I've always just used WAP.  I'm asking the question for someone else and I don't see any information on an answer to this.

we do conditional rendering of custom controls so it's important for us to be able to debug errors during compile time in an .aspx page before it hits production.

Comment: Is this what you mean?  You want the compiler to check the .aspx files for syntax.  When you used VS Web Sites, the compiler would actually do this.  But since switching to WAP's, the default behavior is to _not_ check .aspx files for syntax.  I.e., you get parser errors at runtime.  But you want the compiler to check the syntax so that parser errors are impossible at runtime, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you have syntax errors these can get caught at compile time.  However, if you have bugs in the logic of the program or the look of the page, that may not always be caught at compile time.  For example, if you want to have a specific layout of a form this requires running the page in various browsers to confirm that there isn't a bug.

Tools like Resharper can help some but there isn't a silver bullet for this.  It may be better to have tests like nUnit or WatiN to help catch errors if something doesn't work as expected in terms of finding bugs.

Comment: yea but how can nunit test compile time dynamic rendering of user controls that are conditionally added

Comment: If my collegue says it was possible in a website project then is it not the case in WAP?

Comment: The nUnit tests are more for unit testing functionality while the WatiN is for things in the UI.  Assuming that one isn't wanting dynamic recompilation of code it should be possible under a WAP.